# How do I force visitors to use example.com/index.html?

Tags: .htaccess

I've been researching about SEO lately and read in some article that if I force all my visitors to use example.com/index.html (using a 301 redirect) and not example.com, risk of tagging my site as duplicate content by search engines would be far less. So how do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [R,L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`